# display database in textview based in query

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

sorry if i'm asking simple Q at here but i have no idea to do it. i want to display data from SQLite database in textview based on the query. i already try some example but i dont know why te data do not appear. i try example from http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html and [How to fetch a value from the database and display it in a text view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460358/how-to-fetch-a-value-from-the-database-and-display-it-in-a-text-view-in-android). can som1 tell me whats wrong with it? this is my code to query the data. tq..

```
RelativeLayout main=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.act);

    try
    {
        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("todotable.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT category, name, description FROM " +
                todo + " where date = CURRENT_DATE", null);
        int column1=c.getColumnIndex("category");
        int column2=c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int column3=c.getColumnIndex("description");
        c.moveToFirst();
        if(c!=null)
        {   
            do
            {
                String category=c.getString(column1);
                String name =c.getString(column2);
                String description = c.getString(column3);
                //String category;
                //String description;
                data=data+category+" "+name+" "+description;
               // Data1=Data1+Score+"\n";
                System.out.println("cat "+category+" name "+name + " des "+description);
            }while(c.moveToNext());
            TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.show);

            // TextView points=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.points);
            tv.setText(data);
            //points.setText(Data1);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_crespro);

            }
```

Comment: I would suspect it has to do with calling `setContentView()` last, instead of first. Just a theory, though.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should be moved before accessing any views in the activity.

**setContentView(R.layout.activity_crespro);**

you are trying to access the view' s(like show and points TextView in your example) before setting the ContentView for the activity.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric pointed out in his comment, you need to use `setContentView(...)` before trying to access any views in that layout (TextViews, EditTexts, Buttons, etc...). The reason for this is that those views exist in the layout so the activity doesn't actually know about them until you call `setContentView()` The following link will be very helpful to you in the future

[Activity Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)